# Return the latest date based from a range of columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that counts the number of completed tasks as well as returning the original values.

I'd like to add a new column which returns the most recent date (in this case `task_1_completed_date` or `task_2_completed_date` but in reality there are 20 task fields)

```
     (CASE WHEN task_1_completed_date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN task_2_completed_date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ) AS task_completed_total 
from (select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.task1.date') as task_1_completed_date
             JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.task2.date') as task_2_completed_date
      from table
      WHERE pet_store = 'london'
     )
```

Not sure how to proceed, should I use a subquery here to order the task completion dates?

Comment: Looks like bigquery includes the [`greatest`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#greatest) function.

Comment: you should [provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). note: sometimes what is good for simplified example - does not work well for real case. anyway - samples of input data and expected output usually helps

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Sorry, good point. I'll try to work on one now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use order by

```
  (CASE WHEN task_1_completed_date IS NOT 
  NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN task_2_completed_date IS NOT 
     NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   ) AS task_completed_total 
    from (select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, 
      '$.task1.date') as task_1_completed_date
         JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, 
     '$.task2.date') as task_2_completed_date
   from table
  WHERE pet_store = 'london'
  )where rownum=1 order by 
  task_completed_total desc 
  -- if rownum doesn't work use Limit 1
```

Comment: Use something like `TOP 1` or some other equivalent of rownum in the outer where clause that basically gives only one row

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use GROUP BY and MAX to get the most recent date. see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: for example:
SELECT
column_a,
column_b,
MAX(task_completed_date)
FROM table
GROUP BY columna, columnb